# Overwhelming number of API requests using the Python YouTube API

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api

I made a quick dirty Python script to identify some videos I found and see if they come from YouTube then add the date they were posted. So it scans a folder for files, then for each file it searches for a matching video on YouTube.

Thing is that I tried with a folder containing 12 files, executed the script once and got 1,224 requests, when it should have been 12. I check my script carefully, which is following [this tutorial from Google](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py) but I can't figure out why I hit the 10,000 requests quota after executing the script a few times. My script executes in less than 10 seconds, there is no way my computer could send over a thousand requests that fast.

I thought it was originally because of a bug during development testing which explains the large amount of requests on this screenshot, like an infinite loop, but after I knew it was safe, I waited a few days to run it again today and saw an abnormally huge amount of requests:
[image]

My code is very simple and available to see on [Github](https://github.com/NaturalBornCamper/youtube-scraper), however here's the main.py file for quick view and historical purposes, can anyone see if I'm missing something:

```
youtube = None
try:
    youtube = build(
        serviceName=constants.API_SERVICE_NAME,
        version=constants.API_VERSION,
        developerKey=constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY
    )
except exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
    cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_RED, "['API']['YOUTUBE_API_KEY'] needs to be set in config.ini \n "
                                      "https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/configparser.html#quick-start")
    exit(-1)
except errors.HttpError:
    cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_RED,
           "['API']['YOUTUBE_API_KEY'] in config.ini returned a Bad Request. This means it's invalid or you "
           "have internet problems.")
    exit(-2)

for filepath in glob(join(constants.SCRAPING_FOLDER, "*.*")):
    filename = splitext(basename(filepath))[0]
    extension = splitext(basename(filepath))[1]

    print("Pocessing", '"' + filename + '"', "...")
    regexMatches = re.search(constants.REGEXES.VIDEO_ID, filename)
    if regexMatches[2]:
        video_title = regexMatches[1]
        video_id = regexMatches[2]
    else:
        video_title = filename
        video_id = ""

    cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_BLUE, "Video title:", '"' + video_title + '"', "...")
    cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_BLUE, "Video id:", '"' + video_id + '"', "...")

    hashed_video_title = re.sub(constants.REGEXES.ALPHANUM_FILTER, "", video_title).lower()

    try:
        search_response = youtube.search().list(
            q=(video_id if video_id else filename),
            type='video',
            part='id,snippet',
            maxResults=constants.MAX_RESULTS
        ).execute()
    except errors.HttpError as err:
        # cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_RED, err.content.message)
        bob = json.decoder.JSONDecoder()
        cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_RED, err)
        exit(-3)

    highest_score = 0
    highest_score_search_result_title = ""
    highest_score_search_result_date = ""
    highest_score_search_id = ""
    for search_result in search_response.get('items', []):
        # pprint(search_result)
        search_result_title = search_result['snippet']['title']
        search_result_id = search_result['id']['videoId']
        search_result_date = search_result['snippet']['publishedAt']
        cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_YELLOW, "Scraped Video Title:", search_result_title)

        pprint(search_result_id)

        if search_result_id == video_id:
            print("Found video id match!")
            highest_score = 1.0
            highest_score_search_result_date = search_result_date
            break

        hashed_search_result_title = re.sub(constants.REGEXES.ALPHANUM_FILTER, "", search_result_title).lower()

        score = SequenceMatcher(None, hashed_video_title, hashed_search_result_title).ratio()

        if score > highest_score:
            highest_score = score
            highest_score_search_result_title = search_result_title
            highest_score_search_result_date = search_result_date
            highest_score_search_id = search_result['id']['videoId']

    if highest_score > 0:
        cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_GREEN, "Closest scraped video title:", highest_score_search_result_title)
        print("Score:", highest_score)
        print("Video id:", highest_score_search_id)

        if highest_score < constants.AUTO_IGNORING_MAX_SCORE:
            cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_CYAN, "Skipping video, cannot find good match")
        elif highest_score >= constants.AUTO_RENAMING_MIN_SCORE or query_yes_no("Is this the correct video?"):
            course_date = dparser.parse(highest_score_search_result_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S ")
            new_folder_name = os.path.join(constants.SCRAPING_FOLDER, course_date + filename + extension)
            print(new_folder_name)
            old_folder_name = os.path.join(constants.SCRAPING_FOLDER, filename + extension)
            os.rename(old_folder_name, new_folder_name)
    else:
        cprint(console.COLORS.BRIGHT_RED, "No video results could be scraped")

    print("---------------------------------------")
    sleep(constants.API_DELAY_BETWEEN_REQUESTS)
```

Comment: I think one of the most important part before executing is how much the quota will each of the method costs. See [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for the overview of [quota calculation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage) and basic concepts of YouTube and of the API itself. Have it a try.

Comment: Ohhh ok.. so actually the "queries" per day is wrong? Then I guess they should just change the semantic with the new v3 API quotas and not use "queries", "credit" or something more appropriate should be used IMO, would be a lot less confusing